# Laravel foreach seems to stop at the first record

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a function to check if a user is a Task App Admin

Task Model:

```
    public function isTaskAppAdmin()
    {
        foreach($this->application->admins as $admin) {
            if($admin->id == \Auth::user()->id) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

If I `dd($this->application->admins)` it will return a collection if my 5 admins.

[image]

But if I use this is my blade file it will only return true if the Auth->user() is the first user in the collection. It will return false if I'm logged in as any of the other 4 admins in the collection.

In my blade file:

```
@if($task->isTaskAppAdmin())
 ... 

@endif
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: The execution will exit the function when finding the first return, and the way you do the loop, there will be a return in the first iteration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `return` so that breaks your function.

```
 if($admin->id == \Auth::user()->id) {
               // do something else but don't return
            }
```

By returning a value you instantly exit the function so that is the reason that only your 1st loop works.

Inside your loop you always return true/false so the 1st iteration for sure will send you out.

A nicer solution and will work for what you are trying to do is to use array functions to search inside your admin collection.

Since you are using collections you can use collection helpers from laravel to search inside your collection without using a `foreach` loop

```
if($this->application->admins->search(\Auth::user()->id)){
    return true;
}
```

Comment: ugh! You are right. My bad. Moving my return false outside of the foreach loop fixed it. Thank you!

Comment: Would work perfectly fine without the else.(The second solution, which I think is far better than OP's original)

Comment: You are right else could be a return false fallback at the end of the function but no needed there.

Comment: With the second solution I get this error Object of class App\User could not be converted to int

Answer (score 1):

This always returns on the first loop. Move the `return false` down a line.

```
public function isTaskAppAdmin()
{
    foreach($this->application->admins as $admin) {
        if($admin->id == \Auth::user()->id) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This fixed it. Thanks